# AndroidAnnotations + Instant App - The generated <applicationId>.R class cannot be found

Tags: android, android-annotations, android-instant-apps

I'm currently working on Android instant apps by using the [android-topeka](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka) example project.

Everything works as expected, after I'm using [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) on my Activity:

```
@EActivity(resName = "activity_start")
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

If I want to start the **application**(`:installed`) one, everything works, but for the **instant-app**(`:instant`), I get the following error:

```
:base:javaPreCompileDebugFeature UP-TO-DATE
error: The generated <applicationId>.R class cannot be found
1 error
:base:compileDebugFeatureJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

**Additional Info:**

> If I remove the `application project(':installed')` in the base
>   build.gradle I can start the **instant-app** but with the wrong
>   **application-id** (configured in the `:installed` project).

Comment: I tinkered with AA and instant apps and got it to work (though, with only the base-feature), saw your post too @ https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2017. I actually ran into the `Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml` error, not yours, but after I fixed that, it worked. Would you share what your gradle looks like?

Comment: fyi, `"org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.5.2"` and i added the `library` and `androidManifestFile` arguments (https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/CustomizeAnnotationProcessing)

Comment: @TWL thx. now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, by the help of this [issue](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2017) tracker (thx to Kay-Uwe Janssen). Also thx to jess. Overall it was the setup combined with the  Manifest Finder and the `annotationProcessorOptions`.

This is how my gradle/Manifest setup looks like:

**Base:**

build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...

    baseFeature true

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["resourcePackageName": "com.test.base"]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    application project(':installed')
    ...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...
    package="com.test.base">
    ...
</manifest>
```

**Installed:**

build.gradle:

```
android {
      ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest package="com.test2">
</manifest>
```

**Instant:**

build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {}
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

> With this setup, the Instant App has the same App-Id as the Installed one "com.test2"

Comment: Please update to AndroidAnnotations 4.6.0, which has Instant app support. I believe less configuration is necessary now.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716903/androidannotations-android-studio-the-generated-null-r-class-cannot-be-found):

This error happens when you modify the `applicationId`. The script provided in example assumes that you have declared `android.defaultConfig.applicationId`. If this was not declared, the value will be **null** or it generates **null.R**.

> ```
> defaultConfig {
>
>     // Rest of Config
>
>     javaCompileOptions {
>             annotationProcessorOptions {
>                 arguments = ["resourcePackageName": "<Original Package Name>"]
>             }
>     }
> }
> ```

**Note:** Original `Package Name` should be same as the location of `R` in you activity.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for the Instant App setup.